# Cast not working inside LOG() function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, casting

The `LOG()` function is not working in the following query. I tried converting the equation into float. Still, it's throwing error:

> *An invalid floating point operation occurred*

Can somebody help me with this?

```
SELECT 
    t1.[ID], 
    SUM(1 / LOG(t1.[AttrCount] / t2.clustersize AS Float)) AS 'uu'
FROM 
    [Testing].[dbo].[entropytemp5] t1, [Testing].[dbo].[entropyclustersize] t2 
GROUP BY 
    t1.ID
```

The values of `Attrcount` and `Clustersize` are:

```
AttrCount | Clustersize  
------------------------
    1            1  
    1            2  
    1            1  
    1            1   
    2            1  
    2            1  
    3            3
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks

Comment: @john - your query is wide open to at least two math errors. If you post the error message we can probably help you.

Comment: Error is "An invalid floating point operation occurred."

Comment: @marc_s Does it help you. Sorry I was having my lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Invalid floating point operation` is caused by calling LOG() with a value of zero or less.

You're probably getting the error from the row indicated below:

```
AttrCount | Clustersize  
------------------------
    1            1  
    1            2    <-- this one
    1            1  
    1            1   
    2            1  
    2            1  
    3            3
```

When I tried `LOG(1/2)` I got the `Invalid floating point operation` because SQL Server treated 1/2 as an INT and returned zero, and `LOG(0)` ==> Invalid floating point operation.

If you do this you'll still get the error:

```
1 / LOG(CAST(t1.[AttrCount] / t2.clustersize AS FLOAT))
```

That's because SQL Server will calculate 1/2, get zero, and *then* cast it to float.

Instead, cast *both* operands separately. I tried this and it works:

```
1 / LOG(CAST(t1.[AttrCount] AS FLOAT) / CAST(t2.clustersize AS FLOAT))
```

So your entire query would go like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.[ID], 
    SUM(1 / LOG(CAST(t1.[AttrCount] AS FLOAT) / CAST(t2.clustersize AS Float)) AS 'uu'
FROM 
    [Testing].[dbo].[entropytemp5] t1, [Testing].[dbo].[entropyclustersize] t2 
GROUP BY 
    t1.ID
```

... Now back to the original post's bit about the divide by zero :)

As already mentioned, you're also open to divide by zero with this part of your query:

```
1 / LOG(t1.[AttrCount] / t2.clustersize)
```

This can happen two ways:

1. If `t2.ClusterSize` is zero
2. If `t1.AttrCount / t2.ClusterSize` = 1 (because `LOG(1)` = 0)

Comment: In the second case where Log(1)= 0. Will it not display 0?

Comment: Thanks @John - I just updated that. You'll run into trouble if `t1.AttrCount/t2.ClusterSize` = 1, because that'll mean you're calculating `1/LOG(1)` which means `1/0`.

Comment: Also, the values I am using in my query are from two different views.

Comment: @John - I think I've got it. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: desperately waiting for your next post.

Comment: if you did a case statement, with  LOG(t1.[AttrCount]) = 0 , that would probably fix it.

Comment: @graceemile you were right. Its working for me now. The only thing left for me is to handle the divide by zero thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @John, that's excellent news! I'm glad it's working. Also, great job updating your question with all the data - that's what led to the answer.

Comment: @granadaCoder The problem was with the both values being int. The solution suggested by Grace works or me. All I now need to do is handle the zaero's. Any ideas on that?

Comment: "case when when else end", as I wrote in my response.  That's how you handle these situations.

Comment: @granadaCoder But I cannot decalre a new variable in select statement. What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: @granadaCoder I have the group by in my query making it aggregate query. Will Case still work?

Comment: Anything in the case statement has to be a part of the group by items.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would put in "divide by zero" catching, regardless of the actual values you see right now.

Second, I would use the ROW_NUMBER trick to figure out if it is a specific row causing the issue, or the entire query.

Here is a generic example, where I put in "divide by zero" "catching".
And I show the ROW_NUMBER trick.

If the first run of the query fails, change the value to = 2.

```
Use Northwind
GO


Select derived1.*
From
    (
        select 
        [OrderID] , [ProductID] ,
        [MyRowId] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [OrderID] , [ProductID] )
        ,
        [Division1] = 
            case
                when LOG(Quantity) = 0 then 0.00
                when OrderID = 0 then 0.00
                else (UnitPrice / LOG(Quantity) / convert(float, OrderID) ) 
            end

        from 
        [dbo].[Order Details]
    )  as derived1

Where 
    derived1.[MyRowId] = 1 /* << Increment this by 1 until you find the problem row */
```

EDIT

You need to show all values.

That would expose the divide the zero issue more quickly.

```
SELECT 
    t1.[ID], 

t1.[AttrCount] , 
LOG(t1.[AttrCount] ,
t2.clustersize AS Float , 

    SUM(1 / LOG(t1.[AttrCount] / t2.clustersize AS Float)) AS 'uu'
FROM 
    [Testing].[dbo].[entropytemp5] t1, [Testing].[dbo].[entropyclustersize] t2 
GROUP BY 
    t1.ID
```

Comment: You think I may be having zeros in that equation?

Comment: I think it is wise to code for the possibility.  Change the "then 0.00" to "then 99999999" (for development reason) and it will show very quickly.  But assuming you'll never have a zero for now until the cows come home...isn't wise, IMHO.

Comment: Also, both the values I am using in this query are from two different views. Will that be a problem?